# Power query issue with missing column of data turned to null

Tags: powerquery

I have an Excel file that uses Power Query to pull in data. However, when I return to the file the next day, there is an error. If I remove the Power Query step, and then re-make the Power Query step, the data pulls in fine. However, if I refresh the data from Excel, there is an error. If I refresh the data from Power Query there is an error and it will take me to various steps it will especially error the very next day when pulling the data from a new file. Sometimes the error is within the Promote header step but the error is always for the same column.

For example, after I promote headers, an entire column of data is missing, and the error message says: "Expression.Error: The column 'Text/Text' of the table wasn't found. Details: Text/Text." The original column cell promoted to headers had a / in it. Could this be the reason? Also there is a date above what becomes the column header in that column.

Here's the code for review:

```
let Source = Folder.Files("J:\PUBLIC\"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xls" or [Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each Date.IsInCurrentDay([Date created])),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each not Text.Contains([Name], "#")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows2", "GetWorkbookData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"GetWorkbookData"}),
#"Expanded GetWorkbookData1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetWorkbookData", {"Name", "Data"}, {"GetWorkbookData.Name", "GetWorkbookData.Data"}),
#"Filtered Rows3" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded GetWorkbookData1", each ([GetWorkbookData.Name] = "Summary")),
#"Expanded GetWorkbookData.Data1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows3", "GetWorkbookData.Data", {"F1", "DATE:", "4/19/2023", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9"}, {"GetWorkbookData.Data.F1", "GetWorkbookData.Data.DATE:", "GetWorkbookData.Data.4/19/2023", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F4", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F5", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F6", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F7", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F8", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F9"}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded GetWorkbookData.Data1","TOYS/JUVENILE PROD","TOYS JUVENILE PROD",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"GetWorkbookData.Data.4/19/2023"}),
#"Filtered Rows4" = Table.SelectRows(#"Replaced Value", each ([#"GetWorkbookData.Data.DATE:"] <> null)),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Filtered Rows4", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Summary", type text}, {"SAMPLE TYPE", type text}, {"SOFTLINES", type number}, {"TOYS JUVENILE PROD", type number}, {"ELECTRICAL", type number}, {"HARDLINES", type number}, {"HBHF", type number}, {"Column8", type number}, {"Column9", type any}, {"ES", Int64.Type}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column8", "Column9", "ES"}),
#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Removed Columns", {"SOFTLINES", "TOYS JUVENILE PROD", "ELECTRICAL", "HARDLINES", "HBHF"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns"
```

I tried deleting and re-making power query steps, but I have not found an actual solution or reason as to why the column causing the issue is causing the issue.

Comment: Did this answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the column names are changing each time you refresh, otherwise you wouldn't have code with things like "GetWorkbookData.Data.4/19/2023" in it.

Have you looked at two days worth of data to see which columns are changing? Once you determine that, make things more generic.  For example, change this

```
#"Expanded GetWorkbookData.Data1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows3", "GetWorkbookData.Data", {"F1", "DATE:", "4/19/2023", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9"}, {"GetWorkbookData.Data.F1", "GetWorkbookData.Data.DATE:", "GetWorkbookData.Data.4/19/2023", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F4", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F5", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F6", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F7", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F8", "GetWorkbookData.Data.F9"}),
```

to be

```
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Filtered Rows3"[GetWorkbookData.Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded GetWorkbookData.Data1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows3", "GetWorkbookData.Data", List,List),
```

and using indirect column references such as referring to 5th column using

```
= Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepName"){4}
```